# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript

i have no idea about this error, because i just checked all of other topics and didn't get result.

```js
let demo = document.getElementById("#demo");
demo.innerText("yo");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pract</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @zakaria-acharki How is that a duplicate of this question?

Comment: The duplicate one shows exactly how the `innerText` property must be used.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Not really. In the other question OP already knew how to use `.innerText`, the problem was in the rest of the code (and that's what the answers are about). In this question there are three separate issues, only one of which is related to `.innerText`.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention, the duplicate updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//currently your id is demo

let demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.innerText="yo";

///if your id is  #demo use this
let demo2 = document.getElementById("#demo");
demo2.innerText="yolo";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pract</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="#demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As your id is `demo`, not `#demo`, you need to write your code like this:

```
let demo = document.getElementById("demo");  // don't use #
demo.innerText = "yo";  // Also change innerText like this
```

And for changing `innerText` property have a look at [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). `innerText` is not a method.

Comment: A bit more explanation wouldn't be a bad thing (rather than just comments on the end of the lines)

Comment: its true, but didn't solve main error

Comment: @Tafhim That's because your `<script>` tag is at the beginning of the document body, so when the script runs, `<p id="demo">` doesn't exist yet. You need to move your `<script>` to the end of the body.